# Difference between 1 and 1'b1 in Verilog

Tags: embedded, verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

What is the difference between just giving 1 and giving 1'b1 in verilog code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: @NJInamdar I expect it's been asked many times before, but as it is, it's a good question.

Comment: @NJInamdar, `1` and `1'b1` is the relevant code.

Comment: Note that the size of an unsized number or an integer variable is *at least* 32 bits in Plain-Old-Verilog (everything up to V-2005). The statements below that it is exactly 32 bits are incorrect.

Answer (score 12):

The 1 is 32 bits wide, thus is the equivalent of `32'b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001`

The 1'b1 is one bit wide.

---

There are several places where you should be aware of the difference in length but the one most likely to catch you out is in concatenations. `{}`

```
reg [ 7:0] A;
reg [ 8:0] B;
   assign A = 8'b10100101;
   assign B = {1'b1,A};  // B is 9'b110100101
   assign B = {1,A};     // B is 9'b110100101
   assign B = {A,1'b1};  // B is 9'b101001011
   assign B = {A,1};     // B is 9'b000000001 !!!!
```

Comment: Is 32 the default bit length then?

Comment: @YashwanthGopinath So called _unbased literals_ (eg `1`) in Verilog are 32-bit, signed numbers. It's not a _default_ as such, it's just how it is.

Answer (score 3):

So, what's the difference between, say,

```
logic [7:0] count;
...
count <= count + 1'b1;
```

and

```
logic [7:0] count;
...
count <= count + 1;
```

Not a lot. In the first case your simulator/synthesiser will do this:

i) expand the `1'b1` to `8'b1` (because `count` is 8 bits wide)
ii) do all the maths using 8 bits (because now everything is 8 bits wide).

In the second case your simulator/synthesiser will do this:

i) do all the maths using 32 bits (because `1` is 32 bits wide)
ii) truncate the 32-bit result to 8 bits wide (because count is 8 bits wide)

The behaviour will be the same. However, that is not always the case. This:

```
count <= (count * 8'd255) >> 8;
```

and this:

```
count <= (count * 255) >> 8;
```

will behave differently. In the first case, 8 bits will be used for the multiplication (the width of the `8` in the `>> 8` is irrelevant) and so the multiplication will overflow; in the second case, 32 bits will be used for the multiplication and so everything will be fine.

Comment: I gave this answer because I was reading more into your question than I think you were intending. I see from your comment to another answer that you simply wanted to know how many bits there were in a so called _unbased literal_. Anyway, this answer might be of interest to future Googlers.

Answer (score 2):

`1'b1` is an binary, unsigned, 1-bit wide integral value. In the original verilog specification, `1` had the same type as `integer`. It was signed, but its width was unspecified. A tool could choose the width base on its host implementation of the `int` type.

Since Verilog 2001 and SystemVerilog 2005, the width of `integer` and `int` was fixed at 32-bits. However, because of this original unspecified width, and the fact that so many people write `0` or `1` without realizing that it is now 32-bits wide, the standard does not allow you to use an unbased literal inside a concatenation. `{A,1}` is illegal.